# Deserialization of Json using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net, deserialization

I want to use the following Method with reflection using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
MyType object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(jsonString);
```

This is my approach that doesn't work (ambiguous match exception) :

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MyType",false);
Type JSONCovert = typeof(JsonConvert);
MethodInfo deserializer = JSONCovert.GetMethod("DeserializeObject", new Type[] { typeof(String) });
deserializer = deserializer.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var o = deserializer.Invoke(null, new object[] { JsonString });
```

Comment: Please provide the full Exceptiondetails.

Comment: And what are you asking for? Because right now, it's not clear what do you expect

Comment: What is `MyType` and how does `jsonString` look like?

Comment: Guys, the given answer work for me, I have a lot's of models, and I can't write a switch case statement for them, so I decided to use reflection for deserialization.

Comment: Why not just use the non-generic version of DeserializeObject?  `object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString, Type.GetType("MyType"));`

Comment: @BrianRogers Thank you so much, I didn't know that overload!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting *ambiguous match exception*, because there are two methods in `JsonConvert`, which match the name and parameter types you provided. Those are:

- `public static object DeserializeObject(string value)`
- `public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)`

You have to be more specific to select correct method. Unfortunately, you will not be able to do that using `GetMethod` - instead you will have to scan the methods list and fine the correct one. You can do it like this:

```
    var JSONCovert = typeof(JsonConvert);
    var parameterTypes = new[] { typeof(string) };
    var deserializer = JSONCovert.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(i => i.Name.Equals("DeserializeObject", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericMethod)
        .Where(i => i.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(parameterTypes))
        .Single();
```

EDIT: One more thing I can clarify is: remember that your approach will result in `o` being of type `object`. You will not be able to cast it to `MyType` in compile-time.

Comment: Curious why someone downvoted, since this is a correct answer. Would be really useful if someone commented what they found incorrect or unuseful.

Comment: @kiziu because they crave for the day that that come and say, "we should become moderator, because we flag so many posts..." - your answer was perfect toward all other... in many places, people just gave up... you are the first to put all the condition and filter that one specific one out... Thank You